# How can I setup a "LoadPage" on Selenium in my whole code project

Tags: java, selenium

I'm programming a test automation but every simple line of code I'm using the "Thread.Sleep", i know that is a bad practice insert these command every line to wait for load my page application, My question is: How can I setup a piece of code that means WAIT FOR LOAD in the all my Java project? Because actually i'm using Thread.Sleep but really isn't efficient

Comment: Web driver gives option to set time out for page load. If you set it, the web driver will wait for the page to load up to the time, we have set it before. The syntax is driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(count, unit).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Selenium has just the right solution for you. You should read about using `waits` in Selenium, which would exactly wait for the element to load for the duration of time you want to wait and then carry on with the execution.

You can read about this here on the Selenium [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits). You can read in detail also [here](http://www.way2automation.com/webdriver-implicit-vs-explicit-vs-fluent-wait.php) (it has a Java implementation) or [here](https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/understanding-webdriver-waits/implicit-waits-and-explicit-waits/) (example code is a Python implementation).

Let me know if need any more explanation.

Comment: Im reading these Selenium documentation, but the problem is that I need a piece of code for execute in all my proyect  based on "WAIT FOR LOAD" because all my lanes are integrated with Thread.Sleep (is a Wait sentence of selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

### 1. `Thread.Sleep` :

As you mentioned `I'm using the "Thread.Sleep", i know that is a bad practice` is pretty correct. `Thread.Sleep()` degrades the performance of execution. So Best Practices suggests to avoid `Thread.Sleep()` and use the other alternatives either `Implicit Wait`, `Explicit Wait` or `Fluent Wait`.

### 2. `Implicit Wait` :

`Implicit Wait` is a method to make the test wait for the webpage’s components to load, so that they can be available during our tests. When an implicit wait is implemented it tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0.Once we set the `Implicit Wait`, it is set for the life of the WebDriver object's instance. However, an `Implicit Wait` may slow down our tests when an application responds normally, as it will wait for each element to appear in the DOM and increase the overall execution time.

An Example:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

### 3. `Explicit Wait` :

`Explicit Wait` provides us more flexibility where we can wait for some predefined or custom conditions and then carry on with what we want. Through Explicit Wait we can write custom code or conditions for wait before proceeding further in the code. An explicit wait can only be implemented in cases where synchronization is needed and the rest of the script is working fine. The Selenium WebDriver provides `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedCondition` classes for implementing an explicit wait. The `ExpectedCondition` class provides a set of predefined conditions to wait before proceeding further in the code.

An Example:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your_xpath")));
```

### 4. `Fluent Wait` :

`Fluent Wait` instance is implemented through defining the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition. The user may configure the total wait along with polling interval to ignore specific types of exceptions while waiting, such as `NoSuchElementExceptions` when searching for an element on the page.

An Example:

```
       Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
           .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .pollingEvery(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
           .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

       WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
       {
         public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) 
         {

             WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("element_id"));

             String value = ele.getAttribute("attribute");

             if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("WebDriver"))
             {
                 return ele; 
             }

             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Value is : "+value);
                 return null;
             }
         }
       });
```

Hence the solution for you to `WAIT FOR LOAD` will be to introduce **`Explicit Wait`** and **`Fluent Wait`** as per the specific element and specific conditions you want to handle.

Here you will find some more [documentation](http://www.way2automation.com/webdriver-implicit-vs-explicit-vs-fluent-wait.php) here about different waits.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you so mucho, I will try use fluent wait because the Implicit wait and explicit wait dont load my page...